# Run script on Linux PC over network

Tags: linux, remote-control

I wonder if it's possible to run script on Linux PC from Android device over network. I *don't* want to run a script *on* the phone. I just want to use my phone like remote.

There is a way to make it via `ssh`, but is it the best method for Lambda user? Anyway to make it possible?

Answer (score 1):

you could install something like JuiceSSH and ssh to your linux box to run the script.

There is no apparent problem with using this method with AWS Lambda, although I haven't tried it

Comment: i prefer dev my own app and implement ssh. So i see i can use jsch

Comment: Links to the apps?